# 'string' turning into an 'int' in the middle of the code

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i'm trying to make a bot to give roles on reaction so i found this code but i couldnt get it to work there is a couple problems with it but mainly i want it to prevent someone from taking more than one role from a catagory and that's not working and the role changes from the role's name to the role's id in the middle of the code

```
reactionRolesDict = {
  message_id: {
    "emotes": ["1️⃣", "2️⃣"],
    "roles": [role_one_id, role_two_id],
    "exclusive": True
  }
}

@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):

  for category in reactionRolesDict:
    if message_id == category:

      category = reactionRolesDict[category]

      if payload.emoji.name in category["emotes"]:

        emoteIndex = category["emotes"].index(payload.emoji.name)
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=category["roles"][emoteIndex])
        member = discord.utils.get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id)
        print('check 1: {}'.format(role)) # prints role's name *check 1: one*

        if category["exclusive"]:

          print('check 2: {}'.format(role)) # prints role's name *check 2: one*

          for role in category["roles"]:

            print('check 3: {}'.format(role)) # prints role's number *check 3: 866228966755270656* (prints 2 times, i think one for each role?

            if role in member.roles:

              print('check 4: {}'.format(role)) # this never prints even if the member has a role in the same catagory or even if he reacts to a role that he already has
              break

        
        print('check 5: {}'.format(role)) # prints role's number *check 5: 866228966755270656*
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=category["roles"][emoteIndex]) # if this is commented out i get an error that the role is an 'int'
        print('check 6: {}'.format(role)) # prints role's name *check 6: one*
        await member.add_roles(role)
      else:
        print('''couldn't get role''')
```

if i comment out the last `role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=category["roles"][emoteIndex])` then i get this error

```
Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 267, in on_raw_reaction_add
    await member.add_roles(role)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/member.py", line 777, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'id'
```

i like how this code looks and it's easy-ish to read but i cant for the life of me know why these two issues happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for role in category["roles"]:
```

This [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the previous declaration of the `role` variable.  In python, the scope of that inner variable continues until the end of the function, so all further usages of `role` will use whatever the value of `role` was during the final iteration of the inner loop.

Here's an example that hopefully makes it more clear:

```
x = 'hello'
print(x)
for x in range(3):
    print(x)
print(x)
```

This prints:

```
hello
0
1
2
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the line:

```
for role in category["roles"]:
```

You are taking the list of role_ids from the `roles` key in the dict here. This overwrites your previous declaration of the variable `role`. That is why you're getting those role_ids. I guess you've mixed up usage of the variable `role` here.

`category["roles"]` will always give you the role_id list from the dict. Don't mix it up with the actual role you got here:

```
role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=category["roles"][emoteIndex])
```

Hope that makes things clear.